What is the meaning of - 1. If '<ta g>' is an angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
What is the meaning of the error and how to fix it

If '' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If '' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'

Error Message is :
Error: src/app/app.component.html:29:4 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

29    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:31:4 - error NG8001: 'progress-bar' is not a known element:
1. If 'progress-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'progress-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

31    <progress-bar *ngIf="showLoader"></progress-bar>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:26:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'TableModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

26     TableModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/primeng/table/table.d.ts:1397:22
    1397 export declare class TableModule {
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'TableModule' is declared here.

app.module.ts - Here I tried

adding the schema but no luck.
I have imported all the necessary packages
Imported formsmodule and reactiveformsmodule but no luck

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProgressBarComponent } from './_helpers/progress-bar/progress-bar.component';
import { CitationDashboardComponent } from './modules/citation-dashboard/citation-dashboard.component';
import { TableFilterPipe } from './pipes/tabular-filter.pipe';
import { GenericHttpService } from 'src/app/config/GenericHttp/generic-http.service'
import { NgSelectModule } from "@ng-select/ng-select";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table'; 
import { httpInterceptProviders } from './http-interceptors/auth-index';
import { HomePageComponent } from './modules/home-page/home-page.component';


// import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
// import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProgressBarComponent,
    TableFilterPipe,
    TableModule,
    CitationDashboardComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  // schemas: [
  //   CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  //   NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  // ],
  providers: [GenericHttpService, httpInterceptProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


I started facing this issue after installing primeng. Now I uninstalled primeng but the issue still persists. Attaching package.json for package version details
{
  "name": "ermapplications",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-option-highlight": "^11.1.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "polyfills": "^2.1.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^16.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 16.0.0.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}



please share the app.com.ts file, if repo is public, please share the link

Meaning of this error message -
If '' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If '' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' is that if the package is an angular component then import it correctly in the app.module.ts. I am unclear about the error if the package is web component. If anyone knows please comment

first point check if you have imported the component, there is another way to use components, called web components. They will show up as invalid elements in angular, for this angular recommends to use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to bypass the error, here you are not using webcomponents, so don't use it and carry on!

Modules (TableModule) belongs in the imports array, maybe this is causing the list of errors to appear!
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProgressBarComponent,
    TableFilterPipe,
    // TableModule, // <- remove this.
    CitationDashboardComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TableModule, // <- add here
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  // schemas: [
  //   CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  //   NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  // ],
  providers: [GenericHttpService, httpInterceptProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

